# Unable to purchase Kevlar in CS:GO

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I recently got the beta for CS: Global Offensive, but one thing I've noticed missing from the gameplay is the Kevlar purchase option under the Gear tab.

I've tried joining regular quick match games, community servers, etc., and I have never been able to purchase Kevlar.

What's up with this?  IS this an issue on my part? Or is it a bug/feature on CS:Go?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Casual mode everyone starts with Kevlar and Helmet. You can only buy it in competitive mode.